# Как сохранить xml файл в нужной мне директории (android studio)

Tags: java, android, xml, save

Есть некий заполненный документ xml `Document doc = builder.newDocument();` который я хочу сохранить в папку `assets` моего приложения, каким образом я могу это сделать? В интернет лазил,но не смог найти информации,плохо искал наверное(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во время компиляции они все складываются в одну папку, потому нельзя в разных директориях хранить XML файлы с совпадающими именами. Именно поэтому при создании пустого проекта студия делает класс MainActivity и разметку к нему activity_main.xml - типа,  сортировка - все разметки activity вместе лежат. Можно также делать - использовать префиксы по фичам, тогда хоть отсортировано будет

Здесь можно посмотреть как их раскидать по разным директориям.
https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-put-android-layout-files-in-subfolders-1f7cf07ff48f